# How to send Array from Select List to ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new to Ajax and I can't find any way to pass my data Properly, my Sub-Category is dependent on categories output, my problem now is that when I select 2 or more item in category, the output of Sub-Category don't pile up on each other.

I know I have to put my category on array but I don't know how it will work if the data come on select list.

**My Filter**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
 <select id="assignedCategory" class="form-control selectpicker" title="Category" value="@ViewBag.AssignedCategory" asp-items="@ApplicationCategory" multiple asp-for="@category" onchange="GetSubCat();">
 </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
 <select id="assignedSubCategory" class="form-control selectpicker" title="Sub-Catergory" multiple>
 </select>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
function GetSubCat() {
 $('#assignedSubCategory').html('');
 $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetSubCat")',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
   CatId: $('#assignedCategory option:selected').val() <!--This Part Right Here, I don't know how to make this an Array.-->
  },
  success: (data) => {
   $.each(data, (i, e) => {
    var elem = '<option value="' + e.value + '">' + e.text + '</option>'
    $('#assignedSubCategory').append(elem);
    $('#assignedSubCategory').selectpicker('refresh');
   });
  }
 });
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult GetSubCat(int?[] CatId)
{
 var getCat = db.Subcategories.FromSqlRaw($@"
 select sc.* from CRM_Subcategories sc
 left join CRM_Categories c on sc.CategoryId = c.Id
 where c.Id IN ({CatId})").Select(x => new SelectListItem
 {
  Value = x.Id.ToString(),
  Text = x.Value
 }).ToList();
 return Json(getCat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could get selected array like below:

```
$('#assignedCategory').val();
```

2.Upon you select an option in selectlist, the `onchange` event will be triggered. That is to say if you select multiple options, it will trigger `GetSubCat` function for multiple times and post to backend for multiple times.  **If you do not care with this**. Just change ajax post data to: `$('#assignedCategory').val();`.

3.You use `selectpicker` in your code, it seems you use `Bootstrap-select` plugin in your project. `Bootstrap-select` exposes a few events for hooking into select functionality. I think you could use `hidden.bs.select` event to post your selected array list to backend. This event is fired when the dropdown has finished being hidden from the user. **That is to say it will trigger ajax upon the select menu closed.**

Here is a working sample:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="category">   //add id here...
    <select id="assignedCategory" class="form-control selectpicker" title="Category" value="@ViewBag.AssignedCategory" multiple >
        <option value="1">aa</option>
        <option value="2">bb</option>
        <option value="3">cc</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select id="assignedSubCategory" class="form-control selectpicker" title="Sub-Catergory" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#category').on('hide.bs.select', function (e) {
             $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("GetSubCat")',
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                      CatId: $('#assignedCategory').val()
                  },
                  success: (data) => {
                   $.each(data, (i, e) => {
                    var elem = '<option value="' + e.value + '">' + e.text + '</option>'
                    $('#assignedSubCategory').append(elem);
                    $('#assignedSubCategory').selectpicker('refresh');
                   });
                  }
                 });
        });       
    </script>
}
```